# Update table not working

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I made this code to check whether a user has entered the wrong password 5 times in a row. The code works except for the part where it updates the value for 'blocked' in the table 'users'. I checked $stmt for errors but there were none.

I can't find out what I'm doing wrong

Here is the code:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$username = "pfrolov";
require "connectDB.php";
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT `username`, `time`, `succes`  FROM 
`loginAttempts` WHERE `username`= ? ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt1->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->bind_result($username, $time, $succes);
$stmt1->store_result();
if($stmt1->num_rows == 5) {
    $i = 0;
    while($stmt1->fetch()) {
      echo $username ." ". $time ." ".$succes. "<br>";
      if($succes == 0){
        $i++;
      }         
    }
    echo $i;
    if($i == 5){
      echo 'blocked';
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `blocked`=? WHERE 
`username`=?");
      $stmt->bind_param('is', $blocked, $username);
      $stmt->execute();
      return $stmt->affected_rows;
      $stmt->close();
    }
$stmt1->close(); 
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: `$blocked` is undefined

Comment: That was the problem indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not defined $blocked:

```
if ($i == 5) {
  $blocked = 1; // <-- Here you define the $blocked variable
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `blocked`=? WHERE `username`=?");
  $stmt->bind_param('is', $blocked, $username);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt->affected_rows;
  $stmt->close();
}
```